# How to parse properties/attribute value in xml file in Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I am pretty new to Android and I am struggling to extract to an attribute from an xml using android XmlResourceParser. Below is part of my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.test.savi"
android:title="TestTitle" >
<com.test.savi.settings.BPropertyPreference
android:key="ENABLED"
android:defaultValue="true"
android:title="TestTitle2"
/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is my function in Java function, however my title is some value like @2131361865, I want to extract "TestTitle" from this function. How do I do it?

```
public String getTitle(XmlResourceParser xpp) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        String title = "Default";
        boolean found = false;        
        xpp.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);
        while (xpp.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !found) {            
            if (xpp.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equals("PreferenceScreen")) {
                    title = xpp.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android","title");
                    found = true;                    
                }
            }
            xpp.next();
        }

        return title;
    }
```

I am new to Android, please do not mark this question as duplicate. I greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks.